# How to retrieve an XMLTYPE data that contains special characters?

Tags: character-encoding, cx-oracle

I want to retrieve XMLTYPE data from an Oracle table using cx_oracle. 
the data looks like this:

```
<infos>
 <Comment/>
 <Observation>àéèç</Observation>
 <Level>L3</Level>
 <Duration/>
 <Cause/>
 <Depot> Haren </Depot>
 <Resolution/>
</infos>
```

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import cx_Oracle




# Connection to RTDIAG
try:
    dsn_test =   cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='xxxxx',port='1521',service_name='xxxxx')
    con_test = cx_Oracle.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxxx',dsn=xxxx)

except cx_Oracle.InterfaceError:
    print ("Impossible to connect to the DB!")
    print ("***exit script***")
    quit()

ID_record = 1729

cursor = con_test.cursor()

query = """select a.content.getClobVal() from emb_log a where ID = :id and uncompleted_record=1
"""
cursor.execute(query,id=1729)

xml_retrieved = cursor.fetchone()[0].read() #string
print (xml_retrieved)
```

Here's what I get

```
<infos>
 <Comment/>
 <Observation>aeec</Observation>
 <Level>L3</Level>
 <Duration/>
 <Cause/>
 <Depot> Haren </Depot>
 <Resolution/>
</infos>
```

The special characters contained within the  XML child is not being retrieved proprely. They are converted in 'ascii like' characters.

Why and how to fetch the XML exactly the way it appears in the DB ?

Thank you.

Comment: When I execute this code in SQL_developer: `SELECT DECODE(parameter, 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'CHARACTER SET',
'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'LANGUAGE',
'NLS_TERRITORY', 'TERRITORY') name,
value from v$nls_parameters
WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY')` I get `LANGUAGE        FRENCH
TERRITORY          BELGIUM
CHARACTER SET                WE8MSWIN1252`

Comment: Useful note: I execute this code trough an ssh console and when I run this `import locale
print locale.getdefaultlocale()`
 I get `('en_US', 'UTF8')`

Answer (score 0):

- Set your NLS environment. You will probably find it easiest to use
  the
  [`encoding`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html?highlight=encoding)
  option when you connect.
- for performance, you will want to fetch the CLOB via an [`OutputTypeHandler`](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py)

Comment: I tried with cp1252 (Windows-1252) and UTF-8 keyword parameter 'encoding' (and 'nencoding') in the cx_Oracle.connect() method but I still have the same problem ...